# Do metadata exist on Machine Code level in LLVM?

Tags: metadata, llvm, compiler-optimization

I added my new custom attribute and I can see it on the memory operands of LLVM IR, is there any way to do so on the Machine Code level as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Metadata is an LLVM-IR thing. It can be consumed by passes and then used to generate something on the machine code level, but you have to do that yourself (or add metadata which is already used by some pass, such as debug information).

Comment: Would be possible to use 'DebugLoc ' somehow, then?! It gets preserved all the way down. But how can we have something more general than DebugLoc? Any example, maybe?

Comment: or Would it be possible for us to “transform” the metadata to a new MC field/member during this lowering?

Comment: @eternalStudent Your edit really changes the core of the question, I think it's best if you revert it and ask a new separate question, focusing on the specific case you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok I Will make a new Q :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882939/adding-a-new-attribute-on-source-code-that-propagates-until-mc-level-in-llvm